# How to communicate rails with coffeescript to update page content realtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database, coffeescript

I've been trying to implement AJAX functionality in my web app, and am having some difficulty. On my app, users can like content called "wads". Thus far I've been able to get the liking functionality to asynchronously update the database, but I'm a bit stuck on how to get the counter (displayed next to the like button) to update as well. I'm a novice to JS/ Coffeescript so some help would be immensely appreciated!

So far my approach has been to use the ruby handler(.erb) for my coffeescript code(.coffeescript.erb). The code in the file looks like:

```
$(document).on "click", "#upvote-count", ->
    $("#upvote-counter").html(<%= wad.get_upvotes.size %>)
```

However, I'm getting a rails error staying "wad" is undefined. I'm iterating a collection of wads on the page they're displayed on. The code for that looks like:

```
<% @wads.each do |wad| %>
   <div class="list-group-item wad-list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <%= link_to wad_comments_path(wad), class: 'col-3 justify-content-center align-items-center' do %>
      <%= image_tag wad.image.url(:thumb), class: 'img-fluid' %>
 <% end %>

<%= link_to wad_comments_path(wad), class: 'wad-link' do %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-9">
    <h5><%= wad.problem_state %></h5>
    <p><%= wad.short_form %></p>
    <p class="text-right wad-comment">
      <%= link_to fa_icon("comment"), wad_comments_path(wad), options = {class: "profile-link"} %>
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render 'wads/actions', wad: wad %>
```

And "wad/actions" renders:

```
  <div>
   <%= link_to fa_icon("chevron-circle-up", class: "profile-link", id: "upvote-count"), like_wad_path(wad), remote: true, method: :put %>
 <span class="nowrap" id="upvote-counter"> <%= wad.get_upvotes.size %> 
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do many things. First of all I would suggest to use ajax with the rails way. That means having the upvote link like this:

```
#index.html
<h1>Wads Index</h1>
<ul>
  <% @wads.each do |wad| %>
    <li>
      <%= wad.name %>
      <div id="wad_<%=wad.id%>">
       Upvotes: <%= wad.upvotes %>
      </div>
      <%= link_to upvote_wads_path(wad), remote: true, method: 'post' do %>
        Upvote
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Note that we have a div which has an id of the form `wad_3`.
In the `link_to`, the syntax `remote: true` stands for, make an ajax call instead of navigate to this path. This will trigger `WadsController#upvote` and increment upvotes.

```
class WadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @wads = Wad.all
  end
  def upvote
    @wad = Wad.find(params[:id])
    @wad.upvotes = @wad.upvotes + 1
    @wad.save
  end
```

end

After the execution of `WadsController#upvote`, the action will trigger a view, but the view now will not be an html, but a javascript (`js`) file with some embedded ruby (`erb`) called `upvote.js.erb`. And it should be something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var div = $('#wad_<%= @wad.id %>');
    div.empty().html("Upvotes: <%= @wad.upvotes %>");
});
```

This file takes the updated `@wad`, finds its upvotes counter div, and updates its content, with the new upvotes counter.

Of course in order to have everything working you have to define the routes for the controller.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'wads#index'
  resources :wads do
    collection do
      post 'upvote/:id', to: 'wads#upvote', as: 'upvote'
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to understand more about working with Javascript and Ajax in Rails read the official documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: I'm getting "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" as an error. On line "var div = $('#wad_<%= @wad.id %>');"

Comment: I updated my answer. The code is tested and woring. Let me know how is going.